# MySQL - Recursing a tree structure

Tags: mysql, recursion, hierarchy

I have a database table which link locations together; a location can be in a location, which can be inside another location.

```
location (<id>, ....)
location_parent (<location_id>, <parent_id>)
```

Here's the MySQL/PHP to go down for a depth of one:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM se_locations_services WHERE parent_locationid IN
( SELECT location_id FROM se_locations_parent WHERE parent_id = '$locationid' )";
```

How do I, given a parent location, gets all its descendants locations, no matter how deep, just using MySQL?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587488/handling-hierarchy-data-in-database

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a [**good-looking article**](http://web.archive.org/web/20110606032941/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html) over at mysql.com outlining various ways of managing hierarchical data. I think it provides a full solution to your question, and shows various less simple, but faster approaches (e.g. Nested Sets).

Comment: @Ed the way back machine still has it. Updated.

Comment: Moving on two years, there's a non-wayback machined version of that article at http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ as well. (Basically it's moved to the author's own blog)

Comment: This is why answers should always contain full details of an answer with a  reference to the source, not the reference being the answer

Comment: It looks like adding new nodes to a nested sets table require modifying potentially the entire table though.

Comment: Could you summarize what the article stated?

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question, but since i stumbled over this searching for a solution.

Since MySQL 8.0, you can use a [recursive CTE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/) for this:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE tmp (id) AS
(
  SELECT id
    FROM locations
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT l.id
    FROM tmp AS p JOIN locations AS l
      ON p.id = l.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM tmp
ORDER BY id;
```

This assumes a slightly different DB structure than in the original question (eg. there is only one table containing both parents/children), however, I am sure that this technique applies there as well.

Answer (score -1):

Since mysql statements can return only table-structured data, how do you imagine the returned tree-structure?

It is possible to do a selection with [parent_id, child_id] table, but it requires temporary table and I've seen it done on DB2, not on MySQL.

Check this article for implementation on tree-like structures stored in MySQL: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/