# MySQL SQL N Number of Subcategories Title with ID

Tags: sql, mysql, categories

```
SELECT (RETURN) N_Numbers_Of_Categories_Id From Categories_Table
```

How to ?

My Table : categories

Columns are

```
Id , int
name, varchar(255)
parent_id , int
```

Data is stored as

```
ID      Name       PARENT_ID
1       A          0
2       B          1
3       C          2
4       D          3
5       E          4
```

I want out put like

```
ID
------
1
2
3
4
5
```

HOW TO... Need Simple SQL Statement HERE!

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What do you want to achieve, your question is not clear.

Comment: Can you give another example of what the output should look like? I'm not clear on what you're trying to query from this table. Are you looking for something from all rows, or just one?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you N category IDs from the table, N being 5

```
SELECT ID
From Categories_Table
ORDER BY ID ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. But since you have ID and ParentID you may be interested in the discussion from an other question here on Stackoverflow

- [MySQL - Recursing a tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2378678/397667)
- [good article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)