# Is there a query where i can find the highest hierarchy? (Mysql)

Tags: mysql

my target is to find the highest position in hierarchy. I have provided video below for better explanation.

This is the current query I am running:

```
SELECT * FROM 'agent_heirarchy' WHERE 'user_id'=370524;   / 
          SELECT * FROM 'agent_heirarchy' WHERE 'id'= 24273;      / this is the parent id of 370524
          SELECT * FROM 'agent_heirarchy' WHERE 'id'= 301;       / this is the parent id of 24273.
```

The query will stop here because the parent id of **301** is null. // It will only stop when the parent id is = Null

Video of what I'm currently doing: https://streamable.com/51zxzi

So my final target is, is there a way where i can run a much easier query than what i'm currently doing?

Comment: Videos are not safe/useful/applicable. Provide: precise MySQL version, sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO formatted textual scripts (or create online fiddle), desired output for this data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve top-level parent MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169281/retrieve-top-level-parent-mysql)

Comment: I'm confused. This isn't MySQL.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I'm really newbie to this. However, Can i use the result as a variable in query? Thank you