# Hierarchical data handling based on ID php mysql

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have a sample MySQL table with the columns **ID, NAME** AND **ID_PARENT**.

| ID | NAME | ID_PARENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NODE 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NODE 2 | 1 |
| 3 | NODE 3 | 2 |
| 4 | NODE 4 | 2 |
| 5 | NODE 5 | 1 |
| 6 | NODE 6 | 5 |
| 7 | NODE 7 | 6 |
| 8 | NODE 8 | 7 |
| 9 | NODE 9 | 6 |
| 10 | NODE 10 | 5 |
| 11 | NODE 11 | NULL |
| 12 | NODE 12 | 11 |
| 13 | NODE 13 | 11 |
| 14 | NODE 14 | 13 |
| 18 | NODE 15 | 14 |

And I have the following tree based on the above data and I need to fetch a node/tree/hierarchy based on ID provided.

```
NODE 1
  NODE 2
    NODE 3
    NODE 4
  NODE 5
    NODE 6
      NODE 7
        NODE 8
      NODE 9
   NODE 10
NODE 11
  NODE 12
  NODE 13
    NODE 14
      NODE 15
```

Now if I provide **ID=6 (NODE 6)** then we should have all the PARENTS (with their CHILDREN) of **NODE 6** plus all the nested CHILDREN of **NODE 6**. So, we should have **NODES** from **1 to 10** as they fall under one **PARENT NODE 1**. The extracted tree would be.

```
NODE 1
  NODE 2
    NODE 3
    NODE 4
  NODE 5
    NODE 6
      NODE 7
        NODE 8
      NODE 9
   NODE 10
```

So, how can we achieve the above-mentioned scenario?

**NOTE: I am using PHP 7 and MySQL 5.6.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Recursing a tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378678/mysql-recursing-a-tree-structure)

Comment: @kmoser WITH RECURSIVE is available in MySQL 5.6?

Comment: @kmoser the link you provided did not answer my question because they are following a different approach.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have updated the question. I need to achieve the mentioned scenario where I provide ID=6 and I get all the parents (with their nested children) plus all nested children of ID=6.

Comment: Are you looking for [Hierarchical data in MySQL: parents and children in one query](https://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP and everything with the SQL server you use. PHP only uses the DB server, it doesn't determine what features it supports.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt hmmm then how can I achieve the mentioned scenario?